# connecting a light to a half switched receptacle

Tags: electrical

Is it permissible according to the National Electrical Code to install a light and connect it to an existing half switched receptacle?

Comment: Is this receptacle on a general lighting and receptacles branch circuit, or some sort of special-purpose branch circuit (kitchen, bathroom, laundry)?

Answer (score 2):

I know of no regulation that would limit you from connecting a light fixture to the switched side of a half hot receptacle. Essentially, you would simply be controlling two items with one switch.

Answer (score 1):

No regulation known that limits adding a lighting circuit to a half hot, provided it does not exceed the stated NEC code current limit for that circuit.